# Selenium WebDriver C# find element by href path

Tags: selenium, webdriver, href

How I can click on

`<a href="Vacancies.aspx?param=apply:16 " title="Please click to apply ">Apply</a>`

I have a few Apply links on page. I should click on apply:16 (not apply:10,11,n).

I have a script (watir, ruby ) :

`browser.link(:href, "Vacancies.aspx?param=apply:16").click`

How its should be for Selenium WebDriver C# ?

I tried
`driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Apply")).Click();`
But as you understood, this isnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give a try with below locator.

```
By.CssSelector("[href*='Vacancies.aspx?param=apply:16']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a tidy up to Santoshsarma's work!

```
def <yourbutton> = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href*='Vacancies.aspx?param=apply:16']"))
```