# Finding link with href content

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I used this code part :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209027/1063093

In my case, **I want to select the link where the word edit is in the href**.

```
IWebElement link = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("[href*='edit']");
```

If I remember correctly, `*=` check if the href contains the word edit.
The thing is when I run this line, I get the following error :

> [image]

But the link does exists :

> [image]

I am not aware of the full href at runtime. So I must find a way to make it flexible and only look for the word edit.
I am obviously doing something wrong but I can't find out what. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: You do realize that finding a selector by `css` is very slow in Selenium, right?  The fastest options will always be `id` and `xpath`.

Comment: @Brian Thanks no I didn't know.. It does not have any ID but if I find myself in front of performance issues at the end, I will change for XPATH. Thanks

Comment: Actually, don't use Xpath.  A co-worker of mine just read that we _shouldn't_ be using `xpath` in Selenium so, I will go ahead and eat some crow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be case sensitive:

```
IWebElement link = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("[href*='Edit']");
```

(Upper case 'E')

Thanks to MrTi pointing out, actually, you could go one step further with:

```
IWebElement link = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("a[href^='/Users/Edit/']");
```

This would translate into "an anchor element that **starts with** `/Users/Edit` - providing your link would always start with that, obviously, this would be a more reliable selector to use.

You pointed out you can only look for the word "Edit", so the above *may* not be too great for you, but something to think about. Looking just for "Edit" isn't too great in the first place -> what if there are other links on the page that also contain it too?

Comment: I believe that a better CSS selector is `a[href^='/Users/Edit/']`

Comment: @MrTi, very true, edited! Although he mentions he can only look for "Edit", I've added your suggestion so he can think about it.

Comment: I could go even further by saying `a[href^='/Users/Edit']` is more safe than `a[href^='/Users/Edit/']` :)